# Finding a linear to quadratic or exponential function

Tags: functions, graphing-functions

I have a set of points distributed randomly over a span of let's say, $0$ to $100$. I need to have a function to slightly modify its $y$ position depending on a $g$ variable. When $g$ is zero, here is no modification at all (green line).  When $g$ is $1$ it should look like the red curve on the graphic below.  When $g$ is $-1$, like the black curve. Brown and grey curves show behavior for  $0 < g < 1$ and $0 > g > -1$ respectively.

I have tried several solutions starting from $y=x+g$ (?) so when $g$ is $0$ I get a linear equation but I fail to get points at $min$ $(0)$ or $max$ $(100)$ unmodified.

[image]

Unfortunately my math knowledge is so limited that I don't even know what exactly should my search query look like, what to ask, which tags to add to this post or what would be a suitable title for this question.

Comment: You might want to consider $f(x)=x + kgx(x-100)$ where $k$ is a (small) constant.

Comment: @WW1 I think you need $k$ negative.

Comment: Thank you @WW1.  BTW, I turns out that `k` will actually be `1/j` where `j` is the maximum `x`, in this case 100 so `k=0.01`  My function is now looking something like: ()=+/j(−j)

Comment: Thank you again @WW1 You can see it applied here: https://zoada.com/lp/mac/configura (second slider)